# Deriving covariance of Gaussian of linear combination of latent variable + noise

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to understand this part of Bishop's PRML (Equations 12.31 - 12.38).

If we have a pdf $p(\mathbf{z}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{z}|\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$ and a random variable $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{Wz} + \boldsymbol\mu + \boldsymbol\epsilon$, then the covariance of $\mathbf{x}$ can be calculated as

\begin{align}
cov[\mathbf{x}] &= \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{Wz} + \boldsymbol\epsilon)(\mathbf{Wz} + \boldsymbol\epsilon)^T]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Wzz}^T\mathbf{W}^T] + \mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol\epsilon\boldsymbol\epsilon^T] = \mathbf{WW}^T + \sigma^2\mathbf{I}
\end{align}

where Bishop writes he has used the fact that $\mathbf{z}$ and $\boldsymbol\epsilon$ are independent random variables and hence are uncorrelated.

If we expand the first row of the covariance calculations, we get:

\begin{align}
cov[\mathbf{x}] &= \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{Wz} + \boldsymbol\epsilon)(\mathbf{Wz} + \boldsymbol\epsilon)^T]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Wzz}^T\mathbf{W}^T] + \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Wz}\boldsymbol\epsilon^T] + \mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol\epsilon\mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{W}^T] + \mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol\epsilon\boldsymbol\epsilon^T]
\end{align}

This must mean that the two middle terms of this last expression evaluate to zero because $\mathbf{z}$ and $\boldsymbol\epsilon$ are uncorrelated. But I fail to see why this is the case. How do they become zero?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found the answer myself. Since $\mathbf{W}$ is a parameter and not a random variable, and $\mathbf{z}$ and $\boldsymbol\epsilon$ have zero-mean, we have:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Wz}\boldsymbol\epsilon^T] = \mathbf{W}\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{z}\boldsymbol\epsilon^T] = \mathbf{W}\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{z}]\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol\epsilon^T] = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{0}\mathbf{0}^T
\end{align}

Which is a matrix of zeros. We can factorize the expected value of $\mathbf{z}\boldsymbol\epsilon^T$ as above because they are uncorrelated.

Similarly,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol\epsilon\mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{W}^T] = \mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol\epsilon\mathbf{z}^T]\mathbf{W}^T = \mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol\epsilon]\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{z}^T]\mathbf{W}^T = \mathbf{0}\mathbf{0}^T\mathbf{W}^T
\end{align}

Which also is a matrix of zeros.